DAX Formula Calculate Year-to-Date up until Max Date of this Year
I have the following tables in my Tabular Model:
Fact Table:



sales
Example




quantity
50


date
2024-09-30



Date Dimension:



date
Example




date
2024-09-30


month
09


year
2024



Relationship: sales.date -> date.date
Resulting in the following view (sum of sales.quantity by date.year):



date.month
2022
2023
2024




01
50
20
30


02
30
30
40


03
20
20
30


04
10
10
50


05
20
20
60


06
50
60
30


07
30
50
20


08
50
20
10


09
60
40
10


10
30
20
20


11
20
30



12
10
20



Total
380
340
300



I need a DAX measure to calculate the sum of sales.quantity year-to-date, but only up until the max available date of the current year - in this case, october 2024.
So the results should be (sum of sales.quantity jan - oct):

2022: 350
2023: 290
2024: 300

Optimally the measure would use time-intelligence functions, so I could additionally create a mesaure for "previous-year" values with SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR

is this your sample data or matrix visual ? could you pls proivde some sample data? How many tables  do you have? Do you have date table?

@Ryan updated the question to provide more information about the data model

here is the sample data I used for testing



date
quantity




2023/1/1
1


2023/2/1
2


2023/3/1
3


2023/4/1
4


2023/5/1
5


2023/6/1
6


2023/7/1
7


2023/8/1
8


2023/9/1
9


2023/10/1
10


2023/11/1
11


2023/12/1
12


2024/1/1
13


2024/2/1
14


2024/3/1
15


2024/4/1
16


2024/5/1
17


2024/6/1
18


2024/7/1
19


2024/8/1
20


2024/9/1
21


2024/10/1
fa



and also create a date table

then create a measure
MEASURE =
VAR _max =
    CALCULATE ( MONTH ( MAX ( 'date'[Date] ) ), ALL ( 'date' ) )
RETURN
    IF ( MAX ( 'date'[month] ) <= _max, 1 )

add this measure to matrix visual filter and set to 1

